# Loading a wallpaper (or background layer) in a Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, startup

I have created a very minimal OS X install on a USB stick to use as emergency boot media. Basically what the install is, is a clone of the Mac OS X Install DVD with the installer and packages stripped out. I have my own launch daemon starting an app launcher when the install starts.

The problem right now is that the wallpaper is just a blank gray screen (like the background you get when you first boot OS X and you get the Setup Assistant). I would like to load a custom wallpaper. I've already tried using NSWorkspace's setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error method. This method works when using a complete install of OS X, but not on my minimal one.

The one example I have of a wallpaper being loaded in this minimal interface is Apple's LCA.app (In the OS X Installer DVD/System/Installation/CDIS). It starts the language chooser when you boot the OS X DVD, and also loads a custom background wallpaper. I've taken a look at the binary for the app using otool, and I see that there are some methods for loading a wallpaper in there, but they seem to be private methods used by the app.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? One possibility I can see is just loading a layer behind my app that acts as a wallpaper. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add your image at:

/System/Library/CoreServices/DefaultDesktop.jpg

?

Comment: Can't believe I didnt think of that :D Will try it now. Meanwhile here's the otool output from the LCA binary that shows it doing something with the wallpaper: http://pastebin.ca/1588628

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I've got. Sorry.  :-/

Comment: Managed to figure it out. The solution is just to make an app that loads a borderless window that fills up the screen frame using an image, and then setting the window level to (NSNormalWindowLevel - 1) to have it go under the menu bar. Looks just like an actual wallpaper :-)